# UWP app process monitor & restart when close

Tags: uwp, windows-10

Is there any good application to monitor UWP application process ?
When user close, or crash, I want to restart.

Please advice me...

Kazu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is by adding a fulltrust component to the UWP package that restarts the UWP when it gets closed. Here is how you launch the fulltrust component from your UWP:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher

To connect between the fulltrust process and the UWP process you can use an AppService connection. Once the UWP closes the connection, you can then re-launch the UWP from the fulltrust component.

Here is a sample that has all those pieces included (although the scenario it demonstrates is a bit different):
https://stefanwick.com/2017/06/24/uwp-app-with-systray-extension/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you , Stefan.

I finally chose below idea.

1. Download and Run it.( A free application "[Restart on Crash](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2009/03/04/restart-on-crash/)" )
2. Make a batch file to restart when crash.( [How to](http://www.mrlacey.com/2017/01/launch-store-installed-app-from-command.html) )
3. Using "Restart on Crash" application, Setup like this.

[image]

the batch file like this.

```
@echo off
start shell:AppsFolder\2313d654-0c37-461f-ae1e-31336dde7fb3_sasbmbdd83txa!App
```

After close UWP application, The free software immediately restart !
for me, It is enough.

Thank you, Stackoverflow and Stefan !